# SQL Query displaying 0 as 1.36424205265939E-12

Tags: sql, sql-server, floating-point, ssms, floating-accuracy

I am adding 3 columns together in my select query, Column A + Column B + Column C. For most columns the maths comes out as correct. However, certain columns where the answers should be 0 are coming across as 1.36424205265939E-12, or something similar to it.

Example: My math is 0 + 1414 + -1414. The answer should be 0 but, instead I am getting a result of 1.36424205265939E-12.

All my datatypes are floats. Columns B and C are coming from temp tables and column A is coming from a regular table.

Comment: well...your datatypes are float, so it is expected. If you want an exact result, then use exact datatypes

Comment: @Lamak - doing a convert to decimal gives me the same result.

Comment: Not if you convert every number: `CONVERT(DECIMAL(16,4),0)+.....`

Comment: I'm assuming that you haven't actually written the expression `0 + 1414 + -1414` in your SQL query, you're accessing columns that *look* like they're precisely those values, but one or more of them have that fractional value, most likely the 0 one.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the value before or after the arithmetic to a decimal.  For instance:

```
select cast(Column A + Column B + Column C as decimal(28, 6))
```

should be sufficient for most purposes.

This is why you should only use floats when you really want floating point arithmetic.  For most purposes -- particularly in business -- fixed point arithmetic is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of floating point numbers.

If two floating point numbers come out exactly equal, it's a small miracle. That's because floating point arithmetic is only numerically accurate to within a tolerance called [machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon).

That's so the same computation systems can be used by people doing molecular structure science and people doing astronomy.

When you display floating point numbers, it's often helpful to use [the `ROUND()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql).  For example,

```
  SELECT ROUND(0.0 + 1414.0 + -1414.0, 2)
```

If you don't understand floating point numbers, please learn about them. Knowing the basics in that area is necessary if you will work in the programming profession.

It brings to mind an old joke from 1994.

Intel Corporation had just successfully rolled out the new Pentium line of microprocessors (what most of us use now in 2017).  The first Pentiums had [a defect in their floating point arithmetic, in which certain computations were inaccurate by more than machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_FDIV_bug).  Nevertheless, it was a *very* successful product launch, and made a lot of money for Andrew Grove, the chairman of Intel.

So, Andy Grove walks into a bar. He's feeling pretty good, so he says to the bartender, "give me a shot of your best scotch whiskey."

The bartender pours him three fingers of the 27-year-old scotch, and says, "that will be $20, sir."

Grove puts a twenty-dollar bill on the bar, looks at it for a moment, and says "keep the change."